# how to input the data and make multiple line graph in x axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph

I have 6 column data in excel, each column has different number of rows.
I would like to make them in line graph with like this
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mZj7.jpg)

Here the link of my data [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hmsriS5oEHppyBcfq2USQItK0JKGy4LL/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105108842885523802309&rtpof=true&sd=true)

However I don't know how to input the data in excel and what kind of packages to make this.
Please help me.
I appreciate your kindness!

Comment: Please share a sample of your data

Comment: @ViníciusFélix This is the link of example my data-  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hmsriS5oEHppyBcfq2USQItK0JKGy4LL/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105108842885523802309&rtpof=true&sd=true

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make an example, using the density of the values, for 1R and 2R.

### Libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
```

### Data

```
df <-
  structure(list(`1R` = c(0.52065235, 0.454407916, 0.382303251, 
                          0.391933965, 0.386122039, 0.382303251, 0.391933965, 0.382303251, 
                          0.376475342, 0.424794009, 0.428951127, 0.439056177, 0.376475342, 
                          0.376475342, 0.406675365, 0.308530057, 0.271168123, 0.037713343, 
                          0.119157154, 0.298611542, 0.029875178, 0.073805877, 0.088483911, 
                          0.214084119, 0.018731476, 0.15214185, 0.408674503, 0.382303251, 
                          0.391933965, 0.42442224, 0.501227717, 0.391933965, 0.382303251, 
                          0.391933965, 0.391933965, 0.382303251, 0.382303251, 0.382303251, 
                          0.391933965, 0.391933965, 0.391933965, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                 `2R` = c(1.654094057, 
                          1.654094057, 1.654094057, 1.654094057, 1.654094057, 1.654094057, 
                          1.654094057, 1.654094057, 1.654094057, 1.654094057, 1.654094057, 
                          1.654094057, 1.654094057, 1.654094057, 1.866104207, 1.889711342, 
                          1.56723193, 1.723571083, 1.723571083, 1.723571083, 1.723571083, 
                          1.723571083, 1.723571083, 1.958552936, 1.488851935, 1.30784867, 
                          1.266307071, 1.172478307, 1.219163761, 1.209873388, 1.806941395, 
                          1.181518902, 1.181518902, 1.163574729, 1.1416133, 1.175491771, 
                          1.11782868, 0.943104661, 0.799804258, 0.838634766, 1.126341411, 
                          1.141790756, 1.945580292, 1.708711004, 1.594182435)),
            row.names = c(NA,-45L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

### Code

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value))+
  geom_density()+
  facet_grid(~name,scales = "free")+
  geom_rug()
```

### Plot

[image]

Comment: hi, Thank you very much for trying and helping me. I have a question, is it possible to make x value in y-axis?